# Redirect entire domain

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I want to retire an entire domain since we're moving out of a market.

```
www.ourcompany.no 
www.ourcompany.no/any-url/
```

etc should all redirect to simply

```
www.ourcompany.se
```

without any trailing url, or possibly to something like

```
www.ourcompany.se/to-our-norwegian-costumers/
```

I've tried

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.ourcompany.se/
```

But the result is that all urls are redirected with kept path's and query string, exactly what I not want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead, since you can make it avoid preserving paths:

```
RedirectMatch permanent . http://www.ourcompany.se/
```