# 301 redirect entire domain to a single page .HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

First try:

> Chated for over 3 hours with an representative of one.com. Best advice
>   they could gave me: do a metarefresh. Bummer.

Second try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/page.html [R=301,L]
```

Source: http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/redirect-entire-domain-webpage-htaccess/

Third try:

```
RedirectMatch permanent . http://www.newdomain.com/page.html
```

Source: [Redirect entire domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/502137/redirect-entire-domain)

Goal: redirecting domain http:www.fotolorwa.nl and all pages (fotolorwa.nl/page to the domain copyshopdehaan.nl/ without any trailing url, or possibly to something like copyshopdehaan.nl/page

Comment: second an third try gave me trailing url like /?pagetitle

Comment: Please add the result of `curl olddomain.com/somepage --head`

Comment: The only way you would be redirected to `/?pagetitle` is if either `?pagetitle` was on the original request, or there is _something else_ going on?! The above directives, by themselves, could not produce such a response.